# jenkins workflow regex

Tags: regex, jenkins, workflow, jenkins-workflow

I'm making my first steps in the Jenkins workflow (Jenkins ver 1.609.1)
I need to read a file, line by line, and then run regex on each line.
I'm interested in the regex "grouping" type, however "project" and "status" variables (the code below) get null value in Jenkins . Any suggestions what is wrong and how to fix it ?

```
def line = readFile (file)
def resultList = line.tokenize()
for(item in resultList ){
(item  =~ /(\w+)=(\w+)$/).each { whole, project, status  ->
      println (whole)
      println (project)
      println (status)
    }
}
```

Comment: The content of file is :   <br/>  a=web  <br/>   b=ert   <br/>

Answer (score 3):

`each` with a closure will not work: [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481)

If something using advanced language features works in standalone Groovy but not in Workflow, try just encapsulating it in a method marked `@NonCPS`. This will effectively run it as a “native” method. Only do this for code you are sure will run quickly and not block on I/O, since it will not be able to survive a Jenkins restart.

Comment: I only find `@NonCPS` as a solution in some tickets, but where is this really documented?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables) though probably not well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well,
After checking out some other regex options I came around with the following solution that seems working :

```
def matcher = item =~ /(?<proj>\w+)=(?<status>\w+)/
if( matcher.matches() ) { etc...}
```